# How to correctly do bootstrap tab replacement?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, animate.css

I have a three tabs each consisting of a form,when I click on the tab for login,I am replacing it with the tab for forgot password using animate.css and jquery as specified in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/6qna70my/3/)

Now,I have another tab that I have added to this,switching to the non replacing tab loads the tab below the previously loaded tab as seen here in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vamsiampolu/38rbh2L8/1/).

I would like to see the Login/Forgot Password tab's content hidden when the Register tab is clicked.

I have tried to solve the issue using `tab('show')` and `boolean` based click event handler like this:

```
window.isHazardousForRegister = false;

$('.forgot-password-header').css('display', 'none');

$('#forgot-password').on('click', function(e) {
  isHazardousForRegister = true;
  e.preventDefault();

  $('#login-form')
   .addClass('animated fadeOutLeft')
   .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
     $('.login-form-header').css('display', 'none');

     $('#login-form').css({
       'display': 'none',
       'visibility': 'hidden'
     });

     $('.forgot-password-header')
       .css('display', 'block')
       .addClass('active');

     $('#forgot-password-tab')
       .removeClass('fadeOutLeft')
       .addClass('animated fadeInRight')
       .css({
         'display': 'block',
         'visibility': 'visible'
       });

   });
});

$('.back-to-login').on('click', function(e) {
 isHazardousForRegister = true
 e.preventDefault();

 $('.forgot-password-header')
   .css('display', 'none')
   .removeClass('active');

 $('#forgot-password-tab')
   .removeClass('fadeInRight')
   .addClass('fadeOutLeft')
   .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
     $('#forgot-password-tab').css({
       'display': 'none',
       'visibility': 'hidden'
     });
     $('.login-form-header')
       .css('display', 'block')
       .addClass('active');
     $('#login-form')
       .removeClass('fadeOutLeft')
       .addClass('fadeInRight')
       .css({
         'display': 'block',
         'visibility': 'visible'
       });
   });
});

$('.register-form-header').on('click', function() {
 if (isHazardousForRegister) {
   $('#forgot-password-header').removeClass('active').tab('hide');

   $('#forgot-password').css({
     'display': 'none',
     'visibility': 'hidden'
   });

   $('#login-form').css({
     'display': 'none',
     'visibility': 'hidden'
   });

   $('#login-form-header').removeClass('active').tab('hide');
   $(this).addClass('active').tab('show');
 }
});
```

Comment: Add Code `$('.register-form-header').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $('#login-form').hide();
    $('#forgot-password-tab').hide();
});`

Comment: @vamsiampolu  when you click on forgot password for first time it works and it shows back to login link when i click on it it works but when i again click on    forgot password link it fails to show  forgot password tab...as i saw in jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know this is good approach or not But i solve this..

Here is the javascript

```
$('.forgot-password-header').css('display', 'none');
$('#forgot-password').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#login-form')
    .addClass('animated fadeOutLeft')
    .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
      $('.login-form-header')
        .css('display', 'none')
        .removeClass('active');
      $('#login-form').css('display', 'none');
      $('.forgot-password-header')
        .css('display', 'block')
        .addClass('active');

      $('#forgot-password-tab')
        .addClass('animated fadeInRight')
        .css('display', 'block');
    });

});

$('.back-to-login').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('.forgot-password-header')
    .css('display', 'none')
    .removeClass('active');
  $('#forgot-password-tab')
    .removeClass('fadeInRight')
    .addClass('fadeOutLeft')
    .one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function() {
      $('#forgot-password-tab').css('display', 'none');
      $('.login-form-header')
        .css('display', 'block')
        .addClass('active');
      $('#login-form')
        .removeClass('fadeOutLeft')
        .addClass('fadeInRight')
        .css('display', 'block');
    });
});
$('.login-form-header').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#login-form').show();
});
$('.forgot-password-header').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#forgot-password-tab').show();
});
$('.register-form-header').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $('#login-form').hide();
  $('#forgot-password-tab').hide();
});
```

Working example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/38rbh2L8/3/)